# tcolorbox and minipage in a newenvironment

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, bclogo

I am trying to recreate a bclogo type box from scratch. (I want to use my own icons without having to worry about Metapost.) I have basically what I want (although it could use a little tweaking) and now the problem is turning it into a new environment. (To be clear, I am more interested in how to use/create environments than I am in changing icons in bclogo, so I'd rather learn how to fix the environment than have someone tell me how to make bclogo work with my own icons.)

This is what I want

```
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=orange!10, boxrule=0.9pt, nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,shrink tight, arc=2mm]
\begin{tabular}{l r}
 & \\ [-1.5em] \multicolumn{2}{l}{\icon{BoxIcons/note_icon.png} \hspace{-0.05in}{\bf{\large Note}}}\\  & 
\vrule width 1.5pt height 0.15in
\hspace{0.15in}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\textwidth}
\lipsum[66]
\end{minipage}
 \\ [-0.5em] & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
```

which gives me
[image]

and this is how I tried to create an environment (Clearly, I know next to nothing about creating environments!)

```
 \newenvironment{mynote2}[1][]
 {%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=orange!10, boxrule=0.9pt, nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,shrink tight, arc=2mm]{}
  \begin{tabular}{l r}
   & \\ [-1.5em] \multicolumn{2}{l}{\icon{BoxIcons/note_icon.png} \hspace{-0.05in}{\bf{\large Note}}}\\
   & 
\vrule width 1.5pt height 0.15in
\hspace{0.15in}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\textwidth}
#1
\end{minipage}
 \\ [-0.5em] & \\
  \end{tabular}
  }%
 {\end{tcolorbox}}
```

which gives me
[image]

which I generate with

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.8in}
\begin{mynote2}
\lipsum[66]
\end{mynote2}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get about how to fix the environment. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  You should have sufficinet rep now to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a new environment, just a `newtcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcolorbox{mynote}[1][]{
    enhanced, breakable, 
    colback=orange!10, boxrule=0.9pt, arc=2mm, colframe=black,
    title=Note, coltitle=black, colbacktitle=orange!10, fonttitle=\Large\bfseries,
    titlerule=0pt, left=1cm,
    attach title to upper=\par\vspace{1mm},
    overlay={\node[anchor=north west] (myicon) at ([shift={(1mm,-2mm)}]frame.north west) {\includegraphics[width=7mm]{example-image}};\draw[line width=1mm, shorten >=3mm] (myicon)--(myicon|-frame.south);},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mynote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mynote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!